# Split http traffic for migration, based on payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, proxy

I have a new service that handles incoming traffic.

I want to start migrating traffic from the old service to the new one based on a piece of data in the JSON payload.

The servers host on AWS EC2 behind an ELB.

I don't want to change anything in client side.

The load is about 20K requests per second, so cost is an issue.

I want to avoid redirecting requests  from the old servers to the new ones.

Comment: I've not used it personally, but Lambda@Edge should be able to do this.